# cosmicmind material swift MenuView not closing

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind, material-swift

I am using cosmicmind material swift library and am following the examples code to try to get the FAB MenuView working.

I have copied the code and added the buttons i want, to test i am just testing with 2 buttons. The problem I am facing is with the `handleMenu` function:

```
/// Handle the menuView touch event.
internal func handleMenu() {
    if menuView.menu.opened {
        menuView.close()
        (menuView.menu.views?.first as? MaterialButton)?.animate(MaterialAnimation.rotate(rotation: 0))
    } else {
        menuView.menu.open() { (v: UIView) in
            (v as? MaterialButton)?.pulse()
        }
        (menuView.menu.views?.first as? MaterialButton)?.animate(MaterialAnimation.rotate(rotation: 0.125))
    }
}
```

The full code for this UINavigationController:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class MyTeeUpsController: UINavigationController {
/// MenuView reference.
private lazy var menuView: MenuView = MenuView()

/// Default spacing size
let spacing: CGFloat = 16

/// Diameter for FabButtons.
let diameter: CGFloat = 56

/// Handle the menuView touch event.
internal func handleMenu() {
    if menuView.menu.opened {
        menuView.close()
        (menuView.menu.views?.first as? MaterialButton)?.animate(MaterialAnimation.rotate(rotation: 0))
    } else {
        menuView.menu.open() { (v: UIView) in
            (v as? MaterialButton)?.pulse()
        }
        (menuView.menu.views?.first as? MaterialButton)?.animate(MaterialAnimation.rotate(rotation: 0.125))
    }
}

/// Handle the menuView touch event.
internal func handleButton(button: UIButton) {
    print("Hit Button \(button)")
}


private func prepareMenuView() {
    //let w: CGFloat = 52
    var img:UIImage? = MaterialIcon.cm.add?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    let button1: FabButton = FabButton()//frame: CGRectMake((view.bounds.width - w)-10, 550,w,w))
    button1.setImage(img, forState: .Normal)
    button1.setImage(img, forState: .Highlighted)
    button1.pulseColor = MaterialColor.blue.accent3
    button1.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.blueGrey.lighten1
    button1.borderColor = MaterialColor.blue.accent3
    button1.borderWidth = 1
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleMenu), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menuView.addSubview(button1)


    img = UIImage(named: "filing_cabinet")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    let button2:FabButton = FabButton()
    button2.depth = .None
    button2.setImage(img, forState: .Normal)
    button2.setImage(img, forState: .Highlighted)
    button2.pulseColor = MaterialColor.blue.accent3
    button2.borderColor = MaterialColor.blue.accent3
    button2.borderWidth = 1
    button2.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.blueGrey.lighten1
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menuView.addSubview(button2)


    menuView.menu.direction = .Up
    menuView.menu.baseSize = CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter)
    menuView.menu.views = [button1,button2]
             view.layout(menuView).width(diameter).height(diameter).bottomRight(bottom: 58, right: 20)
    }
    private func prepareTabBarItem() {

        //todo
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareMenuView()
    }
}
```

The menu I have embedded as a subView of UINavigationController. The reason I have added to this subView is because the FAB is on top of a search/display controller (TableView) and this way the FAB can remain on top of the TableView even when scrolling the contents of the Table.

When the view initially loads, I can click on the menu button and the animation happens correctly and button2 appears. However, it does not allow me to hit the second button OR close the menu by pressing button1 again UNLESS I navigate to another tab in the tab bar controller and then navigate back to the tab where the FAB MenuView was located. I am loading my `prepareMenuView()` function in `viewDidLoad` just as it is shown in the example.

Not sure how to modify this so that it can behave as desired. It doesn't make sense to pick another ViewController lifecycle method to run `prepareMenuView()`.

Comment: Hey! Do you mind sharing the full setup code? I will be able to help from there. Thank you!

Comment: @CosmicMind I have added the contents of my viewcontroller now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the issue with your code is that `button2` only has the selector handler for `handleButton`. The `handleMenu` handler is not added to it. So you have two solutions.

1. Add the `handleMenu` call to the `handleButton`

`internal func handleButton(button: UIButton) {
    print("Hit Button \(button)")
    handleMenu(button)
}`

2. Add a selector handler to the `button2` instance for `handleMenu`.

`button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleMenu), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

Either option will work, just remember that order matters. So if you want the menu to close before you load some content, then call the method before or add the selector handler `handleMenu` before you add the `handleButton`.

:) All the best!

Comment: this only works still if i move to another tab and navigate back to the first tab. after hitting the FAB, i must trigger `viewDidLoad()` again in order to be able to dismiss button2 or to even click on button2. the pulse animation does not show on button2 until I navigate away and back again.

Comment: How are you adding this view controller? This worked perfectly for me when I programmatically added the view controller to the appDelegate's `window.rootViewController` property. You are describing tabs... where is the code for your tabs?